# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [index] while deploying JAR in AWS ELASTIC BEANSTALK

Tags: java, reactjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot (2.7.4) with react js in the same artifact as JAR to deploy on AWS Elastic beanstalk. I referred below document to achieve the above feature:
https://dev.to/arpan_banerjee7/run-react-frontend-and-springboot-backend-on-the-same-port-and-package-them-as-a-single-artifact-14pa

When running this JAR in VSCode and access the react js page (http://localhost:9001/home), everything works as expected. But when i deployed the same JAR to Elastic beanstalk getting below exception:

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [index], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

i have added a blank index.html under resources/templates/.
I suspect thymleaf prefix path defined in application.properties is not recognized by thymleaf when JAR deployed to elastic beanstalk. React js build folder is copied to /target/classes/static/ folder as per above reference link and so i am referring this path in thymleaf prefix.
PLease guide me how this can be resolved.

In ErrorController i have mapped /error to load react js page:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/error")
  public ModelAndView mav(){
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("index");
    return mav;
  }
```

Defined prefix in application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:./target/classes/static/
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Project structure is:
[image: Project structure]

Comment: `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:./target/classes/static/` this really won't help for the jar deployment. Also an empty `index.html`? Your react front end should be part of the application.

Comment: React js build folder is copied to /target/classes/static/ folder which has index.html of react js application. How can i access frontend js/css in application ?

Comment: `static` is exposed automatically, you don't need to do anything for this. I also don't see why you would need Thymeleaf at all. Register a view controller for `/` or a adefault that redirects to `/static/index.html`.

Comment: If i dont use Thymeleaf, @GetMapping(value ="/") keeps on reloading on browser giving too many redirect error. Also, when hitting url http://localhost:9001/home, application searching 'home' as getmapping request instead of react js 'home' page and throws Whitelabel error on browser. I handled this with ErrorController to return ModelAndView("index") using Thymeleaf. Any suggestion how can i replace  file:./target/classes/static/ to work on JAR deployment?

Comment: The problem is that you introduced that path altogether. As stated you need a view controller that redirects/forwards `/home` to `/static/homez` you don't need thymeleaf for that, just a view controller.